# stuck on Greens method , please help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

could someone please help me solve this ODE using the greens function method , I keep thinking I've done everything perfectly but at the end it just wont plug back in properly no matter what I try please help !

xDy + 5y = x − 4{x}^3

1<=x=<2

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? This will help us help you.

Comment: @ZachBoyd calculating the homogeneous equation i got y_1(x)=c/x^5. then for the greens function i think its -t^4/2x^5 for x<t and t^4/2x^5 for x>t ?

Comment: Can you please use MathJax? There is a great tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference